# Need to change list items to divs in jquery tabbed content

Tags: html, css

I'm using [this script](http://css-tricks.com/organic-tabs/) [on my site here.](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/pages/community.html#core), but because the jscript is set up for list item ids, I'm not too sure how to change that safely to divs.

It's very simple I know, so anyone able to direct me would be appreciated!

All the code is on the former page and the bit for the height adjustment is this:

```
// Adjust outer wrapper to fit new list snuggly
var newHeight = base.$el.find("#"+listID).height();
$allListWrap.animate({
    height: newHeight
});
```

I just changed the list items to divs and ps:

```
<div class="list-wrap">
        <div id="featured">
            <p>Stuff in here!</p>
        </div>
         <div id="core" class="hide">
            <p>hello</p>
         </div>
         <div id="jquerytuts" class="hide">
            <p>Stuff in here!</p>
         </div>
         <div id="classics" class="hide">
            <p>Stuff in here!</p>
         </div>
         <div id="link" class="hide">
            <p>Stuff in here!</p>
         </div>
</div> <!-- END List Wrap -->
```

If anyone knows and can help that'd be great..

Answer (score 0):

```
hai now check work correctly.
copy and paste your code and run your system.





<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>

             var newHeight = base.$el.find("#"+listID).height();
                $allListWrap.animate({
                    height: newHeight
                });

</script>
<style>
 div p
 {
     margin:0px;
     padding:5px 0px 0px 0px;

 }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="list-wrap">

        <div id="featured">
            <p>Stuff in here!</p>
        </div>

         <div id="core" class="hide">
            <p>hello</p>
         </div>

         <div id="jquerytuts" class="hide">
            <p>Stuff in here!</p>
         </div>

         <div id="classics" class="hide">
            <p>Stuff in here!</p>
         </div>

         <div id="link" class="hide">
            <p>Stuff in here!</p>
         </div>

</div> <!-- END List Wrap -->

</body>
</html>
```